# What should I try next in order to minimise/eliminate java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout spring retry

Tags: java, project-reactor, socket-timeout-exception

I get lots of events to process in RabbitMq and then those get forward to service 1 to process and after some processing the data, there is an internal call to a micro service2. However, I do get java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout frequently when I call service2, so I tried to increase timeout limit from 2s to 10 sec as a first trial and it did minimise the timeout exceptions but still lot of them are still there,
second change I made is removal of deprecated retry method of spring and replace the same with retryWhen method with back off and jitter factor introduced as shown below

```
.retryWhen(Retry.backoff(ServiceUtils.NUM_RETRIES, Duration.ofSeconds(2)).jitter(0.50)
                        .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> {
                            throw new ServiceException(
                                    ErrorBo.builder()
                                            .message("Service failed to process after max retries")
                                            .build());
                        }))
                .onErrorResume(error -> {
                    // return and print the error only if all the retries have been exhausted
                    log.error(error.getMessage() + ". Error occurred while generating pdf");
                    return Mono.error(ServiceUtils
                            .returnServiceException(ServiceErrorCodes.SERVICE_FAILURE,
                                    String.format("Service failed to process after max retries, failed to generate PDF)));
                })
        );
```

So my questions are,

1. I do get success for few service call and for some failure, does it mean some where there is still bottle neck for processing the request may be at server side that is does not process all the request.
2. Do I need to still increase timeout limit if possible
3. How do I make sure that there is no java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

This issue has started coming recently. and it seems there is no change in ports or any connection level changes.
But still what all things I should check in order to make sure the connection level setting are correct. Could someone please guide on this.

Thanks in advance.